# Sending Reactions on Bot messages in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a wyr so the user can pick an emoji. I have used variations of the code below and I'm am unable to get the message to send to the message the bot sends.

I did try the return (); but maybe I did it wrong because it did not work. Here is the code I am currently using.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "wyr",
  description: "Would You Rather?",
  execute(message) {
    message.channel.send(dowyr());


    function dowyr() {
      var theWyr = ["Would you rather...\n\:a: Have the ability to go to the future?\n\:b: Have the ability to go to the past?"];
      return wry = theWyr[Math.floor(Math.random() * theWyr.length)];    
      message.react("️");
      message.react("️");
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message` is the message the user sent, so you need to point the `.react()` method to the message the bot sent, you can use `.then()` for that.

So your code would be:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "wyr",
  description: "Would You Rather?",
  execute(message) {
    message.channel.send(dowyr()).then((msg) => {
        msg.react("️");
        msg.react("️");
    });

    function dowyr() {
      var theWyr = ["Would you rather...\n\:a: Have the ability to go to the future?\n\:b: Have the ability to go to the past?"];
      return wry = theWyr[Math.floor(Math.random() * theWyr.length)];
    }
  },
};
```